# Django ManyToMany relation QuerySet using custom intermediate table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I would like to use custom intermediate table for products and its attributes. I have the following model defined,

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=600, blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True) 
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)     

class Attributes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Products, through="AttributesMapping", related_name="attributes")

class AttributesMapping(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attributes)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products)
    value = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

in views Adding Products objects to context and from template trying to get the attributes by saying

```
{% for attribute in product.attributes.all %}{{ attribute.name }}: {{ attribute.value }} {% endfor %}
```

I am getting the name but the value doesn't showup. I tried inspecting sql statement getting executed.

```
SELECT `attributes`.`id`, `attributes`.`name` FROM `attributes` INNER JOIN `attributes_mapping` ON (`attributes`.`id` = `attributes_mapping`.`attribute_id`) WHERE `attributes_mapping`.`product_id` = 1
```

the value is in 'attributes_mapping' table, Select statement has a reference but not selecting that field.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Please show the code creating your queryset. It's likely there's an issue there.

Comment: In views I just doing this `product = Products.objects.get(url=product_url)` and `return render('template.html', {product: product})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `value` is not defined on `attribute`, it's defined on the through table. In order to access it, you need to access the attributes mapping object:

```
for mapping in AttributesMapping.objects.get(product=product):
    print mapping.attribute.name, mapping.value
```

Alternatively:

```
for attribute in product.attributes.all():
    mapping = attribute.attributemapping_set.get(product=product)
    print attribute.name, mapping.value
```

This is of course means you'll have to change the way you're doing things as these kind of function calls aren't supported from django templates. Without knowing a bit more about your setup, I can't really advise how best to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an `Attribute` object in your template (`{% for attribute in product.attributes.all %}`) but using it as if you had a `AttributesMapping` object. The `Attribute` object has no `value` attribute.